# Add index to TOC with doxygen

Tags: indexing, latex, doxygen, tableofcontents

I am using doxygen to create documentation (a PDF) for a C project.  I would like the index to show up in the TOC.  This is [simple enough](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57427/how-to-add-printindex-to-tableofcontents) with [pdf]latex.

Problem #1: I cannot use the tocbibind or idxlayout packages (see link above).  If I attempt to use these with doxygen

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES = [nottoc]tocbibind
```

then doxygen writes to the TeX source file

```
\usepackage{[nottoc]{tocbibind}}
```

and the extra {} causes a LaTeX error.  This seems to be a bug in doxygen?

Problem #2: This leaves me with the imakeidx package (again, see link above). In the doxygen config file

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES = imakeidx
```

But now I need to change from `\makeindex` to `\makeindex[intoc]`.

Back to the Doxyfile:

```
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME = makeindex[intoc]
```

But this has no discernible effect. Any suggestions for actually getting the index to show up in the TOC?

Comment: I can think of at least one workaround (edit the refman.tex file that Doxygen creates... this could even be done with sed -i and wrapped into an alias) but there simply must be a better way...

Comment: The problem noted under problem #2 is caused by a misunderstanding, the `MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME` is the command to be used in the `Makefile` / `make.bat` to convert the tex files to pdf. For the part in the tex file nothing exits.

Comment: For the problem noted under #2 I've just pushed a proposed patch to github (pull request 715, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/715).

Comment: Thanks @albert for the very useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue as described occurred in Doxygen 1.6.1.  Problem #1 above has been fixed (see [here](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/304/commits/1c47dd436358ffc7bc76901cddc559b2d8ce233d)). In Doxygen 1.8.7 (which I am now using) the index is included in the TOC without issue.

UPDATE: Problem #2 was based upon my own misunderstanding of a configuration option.  See [the comment from albert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394311/add-index-to-toc-with-doxygen/48529497#comment87497471_44394311), who has proposed a patch that provides the functionality I wanted.

EDIT: The mentioned pull request 715 has been integrated in master on github.